# Query nested collection of documents in Firebase

Tags: firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

How can I query a nested collection of documents in Firebase? I have my setup for that which is the following:

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'Seats1' },
        { collection: 'Seats2' },
        { collection: 'Seats3' },
        { collection: 'Seats4' },
        { collection: 'Seats5' },
    ])
)(ReservDesk)
```

This is the firestoreConnect part. Now the problem is that I don't know how to write the query in order to get deeper in the collection. I saw another article about that but that does not work.
Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: There's not info info in the question to really accurately help. Can you include a image of your Firestore structure in the question? If you can't include that, please include a brief textual representation of your data so we know what you're trying to query.

Comment: For now Firestore structure consists of five collection (Seats1, Seats2, Seats,3, Seats4) and each collection contains five documents. So Seats1 contains (doc1, doc2, doc,3, doc4, doc5). Each document contains three fields (id (number), name (string), occupied (boolean). I would like to set up a structure as the following: 
Building1 --> Floor1 --> Seats
Building1 ---> Floor2 --> Seats

Comment: The structure should be the following: Collection (Building1), Document (Floor1), Collection(Seats), Documents(Seat1, Seat2, Seat3, Seat4,Seat5....). I know how to set up this structure in firestore, but I don't know how to write the firestoreConnect query to reach the last collection of documents in firestore.

Comment: Please don't put code or structures in comments - they are hard to read. Update the question so it's clear. Querying a sub-collection is the same as querying any collection - as long as you know the path, it's the same format *collection/document/collection/document*. For example, suppose you have a users collection with user id's as the documents: *users/uid_0*, then within uid_0 you have a sub collection of favorite restaurants with each restaurant being a document, so the structure is *users/uid_0/restaurants/restaurant_xxx* the query would follow that path to *restaurants*

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does not support cross sub-collection queries as each collection isn't natively nested under their parent documents, instead, the document path is simply a relational indicator with no inheritance features.
The closest solution you have is a Collection Group query which searches through *ALL* collections named X and requires an index to be generated.

To make it work with your current request, you will have to create a reference to each sub-collection and query them individually.

```
ref = dbRef.collection("user").doc().collection("Seats1");
ref.where("A", "==" , "B").get();
```

if you want to query inside all sub-collections, will have to restructure your database to contain all seats and the seat number simply be a field property, allowing you to query relationally with the parent rather than All seats for all collections.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the intent of this answer but querying a sub-collection is like querying any collection - as long as you know the path, you can query as normal.

Comment: the user was specifically asking to query through each sub-collection which isn't possible with one call

Comment: Possibly, however the phrasing of the question *a nested collection* could be a specific nested collection. The question is a tad vague but this is a good solution if they want to query multiple collections.